# Kinetis/NXP Freedom Board incorrectly identified as "MCU MOUSE + CDC DEMO"

Tags: kinetis

I've just plugged a Kinetis K22F board into a USB hub, which in turn is connected to my Windows 10 PC.

In Device Manager, this device shows as "MCU MOUSE + CDC DEMO".

I've tried connecting the board to my PC directly, instead of using the hub, but the same thing always happens.

Googling "MCU MOUSE + CDC DEMO" only brings up [this question](https://community.nxp.com/t5/Kinetis-Microcontrollers/How-to-install-MCU-MOUSE-CDC-DEMO-driver/td-p/658114) on NXP's support website. The original poster eventually posts again to say that the problem  was "(my) micro-usb bus wasn't work(ing) very well". This doesn't really yield much information!

Additional information which may be relevant: Before connecting the board, I had disconnected jumpers J10 and J13, to disconnect the onboard SWD.

Can any Kinetis users on here suggest a way to get Windows 10 to recognise the board correctly, or at least suggest troubleshooting steps?

Answer (score 1):

I may have answered my own question - connecting to the device's other micro USB port causes it to be correctly recognised and enables me to connect with PuTTY on COM3.

But I still don't understand why it was misidentified the first time round.

Comment: The demo app on the target cpu is the cdc and mouse demo. When you plugged into the debug usb, that’s when you talk to the debug cpu. The demo app will disappear when you flash your code.

Comment: @Kartman I understood that the demo app was a "bubble level"/"spirit level" demo using the onboard accelerometer. Not a mouse demo.

I don't even know what a CDC would be in this context.